# Random.choice pulling entire list, instead of single items

Tags: python, list, random, imaplib

I am (continually) working on a project with gmail and imaplib. I am searching gmail for emails that contain a specific word, and receiving a list of unique ids (most of my code is based off of/is Doug Hellman's, from his excellent [imaplib tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/imaplib/)). Those unique ids are saved to a list. I am trying to pull a single id from the list, but random.choice keeps pulling the entire list. Here is the code:

```
import imaplib
import random
from imaplib_list_parse import parse_list_response

c = imaplib_connect.open_connection()
msg_ids = []
c.select('[Gmail]/Chats', readonly=True)
typ, msg_ids = c.search(None, '(BODY "friend")')
random_id = random.choice(msg_ids)
print random_id
```

I've messed around in the interpreter and msg_ids is definitely a list. I've also attempted to pull specific elements of the array (ex: msg_ids[1] etc) but it says "IndexError: list index out of range" which I understand to mean "the thing you are looking for isn't there", which is confusing because it is there.

Is there anytime a list is not a list? Or something? I'm confused.

As always, I appreciate any feedback the wonderful people of stackoverflow could give :)

Comment: I'm confused.  You have a search_body() function, but it's never called, so msg_ids is still an empty list, which would certainly cause random.choice() to raise an IndexError. Later, `print random` would print some information about the random module, not random_id.  Is this the code you ran, or are there indentation errors/missing lines?

Comment: Ah whoops, I just realized that I've been working in the interpreter and this is the code that was sitting in sublime. I've revised to show a more accurate piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think random_id is a list of list, something like: `[[1,2,3,5]]`。So when you call `msg_ids[1]`, it raise `IndexError`. And since there is only one element in the list, `random.choice()` always return the element. You can try:

```
print random.choice(msg_ids[0])
```

To debug this kind of things, you can try print the `random_id`, or use `IPython` to interactive your code to find out the problem.

Comment: Hm, that's pulling up random numbers, but not specifically the numbers of the unique ids in the list. Strangely, when I do a len on the list (len(msg_ids)) it turns "1".